# Nested macros using FPeval

Tags: macros, fp

I am trying to create an easy to use template, with a part that would look like this:

[image]

The original code I used to do this is the following:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{tableGray}
Phase & Intitulé & Prix unitaire (€ HT) & Nombre de Jours-Etude Homme & Prix (€ HT) \\
\hline
1 & Nom de la phase 1 & 380.00 & 3 & 1140.00 \\
\hline
2 & Nom de la phase 2 & 380.00 & 1 & 380.00 \\
\hline
3 & Nom de la phase 3 & 380.00 & 4 & 1520.00 \\
\hline
TOTAL des prestations (€ HT) &  & 380.00 & 8 & 3040.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
```

I am trying to define custom commands, in order to automate calculation and to make it super easy to use. The first column would use a counter that auto-increment, and the last column would be the product of the 3rd and the 4th.

For exemple, I'ld like the people I will give this template to, to be able to do that with:

```
\tableauBudgetA{380}{
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 1}{3}
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 2}{1}
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 3}{4}
}
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
\usepackage{fp}
```

[...]

```
\newcommand{\tableauBudgetA}[2]{
\FPeval{prixUnitaireJEH}{round(#1,2)}
\FPeval{totalJEH}{0}
\FPeval{cntPhase}{0}
\FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(0,2)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{tableGray}
Phase & Intitulé & Prix unitaire (€ HT) & Nombre de Jours-Etude Homme & Prix (€ HT) \\
\hline
#2
TOTAL des prestations (€ HT) &  & \prixUnitaireJEH & \totalJEH & \totalJEHprix \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip
}

\newcommand{\ligneBudgetA}[2]{
\FPeval{cntPhase}{clip(cntPhase+1)}
\FPeval{totalJEH}{clip(totalJEH+#2)}
\FPeval{prixPhase}{round(#2 * prixUnitaireJEH,2)}
\FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(totalJEHprix+prixPhase,2)}
\cntPhase & #1 & \prixUnitaireJEH & #2 & \prixPhase \\\hline
}
```

However, this does not behave as intended:

[image]

I have been searching for a few hours now I suspect this has something to do with variables scope, but I can't figure it out.

Any idea? Thanks.

PS: This is my 1st time using this forum, so please tell me if I have forgotten useful information.

EDIT: As suggested by Rmano, here is a compilable version of my code.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fp}

\definecolor{tableGray}{RGB}{220, 180, 180}

\newcommand{\tableauBudgetA}[2]{
\FPeval{prixUnitaireJEH}{round(#1,2)}
\FPeval{totalJEH}{0}
\FPeval{cntPhase}{0}
\FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(0,2)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{tableGray}
Phase & Intitulé & Prix unitaire (€ HT) & Nombre de Jours-Etude Homme & Prix (€ HT) \\
\hline
#2
TOTAL des prestations (€ HT) &  & \prixUnitaireJEH & \totalJEH & \totalJEHprix \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip
}

\newcommand{\ligneBudgetA}[2]{ %Nom de la phase ; Nombre de JEH
\FPeval{cntPhase}{clip(cntPhase+1)}
\FPeval{totalJEH}{clip(totalJEH+#2)}
\FPeval{prixPhase}{round(#2 * prixUnitaireJEH,2)}
\FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(totalJEHprix+prixPhase,2)}

\cntPhase & #1 & \prixUnitaireJEH & #2 & \prixPhase \\\hline
}

\begin{document}

\tableauBudgetA{380}{
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 1}{3}
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 2}{1}
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 3}{4}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Rmano for the advice, I have edited my post to include a compilable version of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your attempt.

First problem: you're doing the computations in a table cell, so the results are forgotten as the cell ends. This can be fixed by “globalizing” the variables containing the totals.

Second problem: you need to expand the variables before passing the row to the table scanner.

Third issue: `tabularx` processes the material three times. So the total you'd get is three times the expected value.

One solution is to avoid `tabularx`, computing by hand the width. With a recent TeX distribution, `\expanded` avoids globalizing all variables.

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\definecolor{tableGray}{RGB}{220, 180, 180}

\newcolumntype{L}{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-10\tabcolsep-6\arrayrulewidth)/5\relax}}

\newcommand{\tableauBudgetA}[2]{%
  \FPeval{prixUnitaireJEH}{round(#1,2)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEH}{0}%
  \FPeval{cntPhase}{0}%
  \FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(0,2)}%
  \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{|L|L|L|L|L|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{tableGray}
  Phase & Intitulé & Prix unitaire (€~HT) & Nombre de Jours-Etude Homme & Prix (€~HT) \\
  \hline
  #2
  TOTAL des prestations (€~HT) &  & \prixUnitaireJEH & \totalJEH & \totalJEHprix \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \bigskip
}
\newcommand{\ligneBudgetA}[2]{% Nom de la phase ; Nombre de JEH
  \FPeval{cntPhase}{clip(cntPhase+1)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEH}{clip(totalJEH+#2)}%
  \global\let\totalJEH\totalJEH
  \FPeval{prixPhase}{round(#2 * prixUnitaireJEH,2)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(totalJEHprix+prixPhase,2)}%
  \global\let\totalJEHprix\totalJEHprix
  \expanded{\cntPhase & #1 & \prixUnitaireJEH & #2 & \prixPhase} \\\hline
}

\begin{document}

\tableauBudgetA{380}{%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 1}{3}%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 2}{1}%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 3}{4}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative way is to build the table storing the various parts in a token register and then delivering it at once.

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\definecolor{tableGray}{RGB}{220, 180, 180}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newtoks\tabletoks

\newcommand{\tableauBudgetA}[2]{%
  \FPeval{prixUnitaireJEH}{round(#1,2)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEH}{0}%
  \FPeval{cntPhase}{0}%
  \FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(0,2)}%
  % start the table
  \tabletoks={%
    \par\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|L|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{tableGray}
    Phase & Intitulé & Prix unitaire (€~HT) & Nombre de Jours-Etude Homme & Prix (€~HT) \\
    \hline
  }%
  % process the rows
  #2%
  % deliver the contents and end the table
  \the\tabletoks
  TOTAL des prestations (€~HT) &  & \prixUnitaireJEH & \totalJEH & \totalJEHprix \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}%
  \bigskip
}
\newcommand{\ligneBudgetA}[2]{% Nom de la phase ; Nombre de JEH
  \FPeval{cntPhase}{clip(cntPhase+1)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEH}{clip(totalJEH+#2)}%
  \FPeval{prixPhase}{round(#2 * prixUnitaireJEH,2)}%
  \FPeval{totalJEHprix}{round(totalJEHprix+prixPhase,2)}%
  \tabletoks=\expandafter{%
    \the\expandafter\tabletoks\expanded{%
      \cntPhase & \unexpanded{#1} & \prixUnitaireJEH & #2 & \prixPhase
    } \\\hline
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableauBudgetA{380}{%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 1}{3}%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 2}{1}%
\ligneBudgetA{Nom de la phase 3}{4}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You solved my problem. I must admit I had nerver heard of expansion, so I will have to read about it.

Comment: @Victor I added an alternative way where `tabularx` can be used.